# how to check software installed in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

i have created an installer using NSIS to install a software say googletalk in my system using following NSIS script ,

```
Name "installer"
OutFile "new_setup.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\Google talk"

Section
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  execWait '$DESKTOP\googletalk-setup.exe'

SectionEnd
```

Now if i execute the installer once again, before installing it should check whether that software already exists or not.

So in **NSIS** how to achieve it ?.

Please tell me with code.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During installation, you need to create informations for uninstall in registry. (visible in Add/remove program on Windows control panel)

I advice you to follow this example :

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs

Then on your ".onInit" function, you just have to check these values with a ReadRegStr :

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2.12

Hope this can help you.